# How can I dismiss a notify-send notification with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: notify-send

How can I dismiss one of these notifications with a keyboard shortcut?

[image]

I am calling it with the `notify-send` command, although I'd like to to work on all notifications.

Answer (score 0):

just came across this searching for my own solution. i found in keyboard shortcuts there is a reference to "Focus the active notification" which you can set to whatever hotkey you want, then use `esc` key to dismiss.